# Файлы Cookie - типы

Tags: http, cookie, https

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот, как я понял cookie существуют минимум двух типов:

-сессионные.

-с таймаутом.

Если с таймаутными куками вроде понятно - это если, когда мне нужно к примеру залогинится на сайте, я отправлю серверу все необходимые данные и сервер возвращает мне куки с определенным временем действия и после истечения сервер эти куки уже не принимает и я опять отправляю форму авторизации.

А вот с сессионными без времени действия не понятны, то есть к примеру опять - я залогинился, сервер мне выслал куки, я их сохранил. Закрыл условный "браузер". Через год открыл, вставил эти сохраненные куки и сервер их примет что ли получается ?

Comment: «сервер их примет что ли» — это зависит от конкретной реализации конкретного сервера. Если он не проверяет никаких сроков годности, то примет

Answer (score 0):

В сессионных куках есть идентификатор сессии (session ID). Когда вы закрываете браузер и открывает его опять, то этот идентификатор меняется и уже не будет совпадать с тем, который в куках. Поэтому сервер не примет.

Comment: но куки не обязательно посылать из браузера, я специально написал - условный "браузер". Предположим я шлю запрос на сервер напрямую через сокеты. И никакой session ID - не меняю. Вот в этом случае что, тогда будет ?

Comment: или Вы имеете ввиду, что на стороне сервера, сервер выдает куки, далее если сервер видит, что сокет Клиента закрылся, то удаляет у себя на сервере запись об этих куках и эти куки уже больше не принимает ?

Comment: «этот идентификатор меняется» — кем и когда меняется?

Comment: @andreymal сервером